# Pythonic - How to initialize a construtor with multiple arguments and validate

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm a python noob and I'm trying to solve my problems the 'pythonic' way. I have a class, who's `__init__` method takes 6 parameters. I need to validate each param and throw/raise an Exception if any fails to validate.

Is this the right way?

```
class DefinitionRunner:
    def __init__(self, canvasSize, flightId, domain, definitionPath, harPath):
        self.canvasSize = canvasSize
        self.flightId   = flightId
        self.domain     = domain
        self.harPath    = harPath
        self.definitionPath = definitionPath

        ... bunch of validation checks...
        ... if fails, raise ValueError ...
```

Comment: This looks fine. Is there any particular reason you think this might not be a good approach?

Comment: What types of validation are you doing?  Much of the time, that's not completely necessary...

Comment: The validation is pretty basic, just making sure some specific values are set and all vars are not empty ... values are required.

Comment: @NPE - I wasn't sure if I was missing python specific capabilities for dealing with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, that looks like the way you'd do it.  Though strictly speaking, you might as well do validation before rather than after assignment, especially if assignment could potentially be time or resource intensive.  Also, style convention says not to align assignment blocks like you are.

Comment: I ended up going with this, because, well it's the least amount of work at the moment and makes sense for the application. However, I like jkozera's answer and will probably implement that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the variables to be settable independently of `__init__`, you could use [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) to implement validations in separate methods.

They work only for new style classes though, so you need to define the class as `class DefinitionRunner(object)`

So for example,

```
    @property
    def canvasSize(self):
        return self._canvasSize

    @canvasSize.setter
    def canvasSize(self, value):
        # some validation here
        self._canvasSize = value
```

Comment: Usually you end up writing a lot of boiler plate code when you do something like this.  The advantage however is that after the class instances has been initialized, you still have the safety of knowing that the user can't reset the attribute to something which doesn't check out OK.

Comment: You could avoid the boilerplate to a large extent by overriding `__setattr__`, but then you either end up bloating that method, or delegating to a bunch of other methods anyway.  You can at least skip writing a bunch of setters that way though.  You could also write your own decorator around `property` that generates a getter automatically and just takes a setter.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this in python. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't select this now, because it's not what I've decided to do, but this is a good answer and I'm going to look more into.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like you did it. Except the validating stuff. I would validate in a setter method and use it to set the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Make a validator for each type of input. Make a helper function to run validation:

```
def validate_and_assign(obj, items_d, validators):
    #validate all entries
    for key, validator in validators.items():
        if not validator[key](items_d[key]):
            raise ValueError("Validation for %s failed" % (key,))

    #set all entries
    for key, val in items_d.items():
        setattr(obj, key, val)
```

Which you'd use like this:

```
class DefinitionRunner:
    validators = {
        'canvasSize': canvasSize_validator,
        'flightId': flightId_validator,
        'domain': domain_validator,
        'definitionPath': definitionPath_validator,
        'harPath': harPath_validator,
    }

    def __init__(self, canvasSize, flightId, domain, definitionPath, harPath):
        validate_and_assign(self, {
            'canvasSize': canvasSize,
            'flightId': flightId,
            'domain': domain,
            'definitionPath': definitionPath,
            'harPath': harPath,
        }, DefinitionRunner.validators)
```

The validators might be the same function, of course, if the data type is the same.

Comment: This logic only makes sense around an object, so just put it directly in the class, or in a mixin.  Then you can do nice things like provide a `register` method to add new validators to the class.  Or if the validators are simple, just forgo the external infrastructure completely, write the validators as lambdas directly in the dictionary, then iterate over them while assigning in `__init__`.

Comment: yea a mixin is prob the best bet here, with class methods to register validators

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly "Pythonic", but I've defined a function decorator called require_type. (To be honest, I think I found it somewhere online.)

```
def require_type(my_arg, *valid_types):
'''
    A simple decorator that performs type checking.

    @param my_arg: string indicating argument name
    @param valid_types: list of valid types
'''
def make_wrapper(func):
    if hasattr(func, 'wrapped_args'):
        wrapped = getattr(func, 'wrapped_args')
    else:
        body = func.func_code
        wrapped = list(body.co_varnames[:body.co_argcount])

    try:
        idx = wrapped.index(my_arg)
    except ValueError:
        raise(NameError, my_arg)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        def fail():
            all_types = ', '.join(str(typ) for typ in valid_types)
            raise(TypeError, '\'%s\' was type %s, expected to be in following list: %s' % (my_arg, all_types, type(arg)))

        if len(args) > idx:
            arg = args[idx]
            if not isinstance(arg, valid_types):
                fail()
        else:
            if my_arg in kwargs:
                arg = kwargs[my_arg]
                if not isinstance(arg, valid_types):
                    fail()

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper.wrapped_args = wrapped
    return wrapper
return make_wrapper
```

Then, to use it:

```
class SomeObject(object):

    @require_type("prop1", str)
    @require_type("prop2", numpy.complex128)
    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2):
        pass
```

Comment: Cool - that's an interesting way to do it. I'll consider this, thanks.

Comment: You can also use assert statements. I've been using PyCharm IDE, and if you assert a variable is a certain type, PyCharm can give you code completion. For example, I have a class called `Email`. If I add a line in a function: `assert isinstance(email, Email)`, PyCharm will know the code completion options for the Email class.